# Как обновить значения переменных, содержащихся внутри функции?

Tags: c++

Как мне обновлять значения переменных, содержащихся внутри функции? Функция сама до main определена. Внутри main я меняю одну из переменных функции, например, внутри функции было (char a = '1'), а потом в main я хочу поменять на (char a = '2') и при этом обновить функцию, чтоб там уже а была равна двум и при выводе отображалась двойка, а не 1.

Comment: 17% принятых. хм...

Comment: сколько всего придумали: классы, структуры, статические глобальные переменные. используй из этого что душе угодно.

Comment: Нифига не понятно. Минус.

Comment: Если уж очень-очень хочется так сделать, переменную внутри функции надо объявить статической и каким-либо образом получить на нее указатель. Однако же, вариант с классом/структурой безусловно предпочтительней.

Answer (score 4):

```
int global_var = 1;
void function_()
{
    std::cout << "\nзначение=" << global_var;
}

int main()
{
    function_();
    global_var = 2;
    function_();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Фокус со статической переменной (то о чем писал [@nnesterov](/users/8778/nnesterov) в комменте к вопросу):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * f()
{
    static int s = 0; // инициализация статической переменной происходит один раз при запуске программы
    printf("%d\n",s);
    return &s; // возвращаем указатель на статическую переменную
}

int main()
{
    int * s = f(); // получаем указатель на статическую переменную функции f()
    *s = 1;
    f();
    return 0
}
```

Вывод:

```
0
1
```

В отличие от стековых переменных, статические переменные физически хранятся в секции данных, поэтому не затираются, если между вызовами функции f() произойдет вызов какой-либо другой функции. Но в любом случае подобное использование статических переменных - это грязный хак. Локальные переменные - на то и локальные, чтобы не быть видимыми за пределами функции.

Comment: А смысл в такой статической переменной? Они же насколько я понимаю существуют только для ограничения области видимости и чтобы не загромождать глобальные переменные (и то это относится к коду, в самой откомпилированной программе один фиг). Кстати, есть вроде еще extern static, он и без этого хака сработает, но я его никогда не использовал

Comment: >А смысл в такой статической переменной?

Вопрос не ко мне, а к топикстартеру) Лично я тоже особой необходимости в подобных манипуляциях не вижу.
Приведенный пример кода просто показывает что таки да, можно обновить извне значения локальных переменных.

Comment: Не при запуске программы, а при первом заходе в функцию. То есть, это, конечно, `implementation-specific,` но `gcc` и `cl` генерят код с логикой `lazy` инициализации.

Comment: @Котик, а как Вы проверяли?

Я вот посмотрел на .o а там константы в **static int уже лежат**. Посмотрел смещение от глобальной, потом распечатал (используя смещение от глобальной), до обращения к функции - печатаются, в ней - тоже, изменил значение (по адресу) и вызвал - что менял извне, то и печатает.

Т.е. никакого кода для инициализации константами IMHO gcc не делает. Все во время компиляции.

Comment: @avp

- Да, я вспомнил детали - я проверял кейсы, когда компилятор не может понять, что перед ним константное выражение, то есть, скажем, если написать `static int i = method_call()`. В таком случае ассемблерный листинг будет иметь вид `test-and-set` и инициализация будет происходить при первом вызове.

- Для кейса `static int i = 0;`, это, конечно же неправда, и для него мой комментарий неверен. Извините :)

Answer (score 2):

```
using namespace std;
//используем ссылку
void f(char &s)
{
    cout << s;
}

int main()
{
    char ch;
    f(&ch);
    return 0;
}
```

И вообще фраза **Функция сама до мейна идет** очень некорректна, так как выполнение программы начинается с функции main, а из неё уже вызываются все функции...  так, например

```
int main()
{
    char x = '1';
    f(x);           //f получит 1

    x = '2';
    f(x);           //f получит 2

    x = '9';
    f(x);           //f получит 9

    return 0;
}
```